# RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (10) must match the size of tensor b (35000) at non-singleton dimension 1

Tags: python, pytorch

```
data = b1.send(bob)
data.shape  # torch.Size([35000, 1, 28, 28]) 


pred = model(data)
pred.shape #torch.Size([35000, 10])


class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(784, 500)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(500, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = x.view(-1, 784)
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return x
model=Net()


for i in range(10):

    # Train Bob's Model
    opt.zero_grad()
    pred = model(data)
    loss = criterion(pred, target.view(1, -1))
    loss.backward()

    opt.step()
```

This throws the error:

```
RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (10) must match the size of tensor b (35000) at non-singleton dimension 1
```

Comment: I think you need to read about PyTorch data loaders and how to represent data in a neural network. You're feeding your entire data corpus at once.

Comment: You've also got `target.view(1, -1)`, which doesn't make sense to me. What is your criterion? Your target is being represented as a `[1,35000]` tensor which won't match your predicted size, which will be `[35000, 10]`. Did you mean `target.view(-1,1)`?

Comment: criterion = nn.MSELoss()